# Blackmagic DirectShow Framerate - Why am I not getting all of the video modes that my capture device is capable of?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, video, directshow, video-capture

I recently started experimenting with the DirectShow Examples of the BlackMagic SDK.
I made my first application but I experienced some strange behaviour when reading the available Video modes of the Card (a DeckLink Studio 4K).
Sidenote: same behaviour happens on Windows 7 Prof. & HP x64 and Win 8.1 Pro x64.

**My Problem is, that I am not getting Video modes like 25p, 29.97p and 30p.
Although the capture device is capable of them, even more they work perfectly with Blackmagic Media Express.**

```
HRESULT CDecklinkCaptureDlg::PopulateVideoControl()
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
if (m_pVideoCapture)
{
    int count = m_videoFormatCtrl.GetCount();
    if (count)
    {
        for (int item=0; item<count; ++item)
        {
            DeleteMediaType((AM_MEDIA_TYPE*)m_videoFormatCtrl.GetItemData(item));
        }
        m_videoFormatCtrl.ResetContent();
    }

    CComPtr<IAMStreamConfig> pISC = NULL;
    hr = CDSUtils::FindPinInterface(m_pVideoCapture, &MEDIATYPE_Video, PINDIR_OUTPUT, IID_IAMStreamConfig, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pISC));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        int count, size;
        hr = pISC->GetNumberOfCapabilities(&count, &size);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (sizeof(VIDEO_STREAM_CONFIG_CAPS) == size)
            {
                AM_MEDIA_TYPE* pmt = NULL;
                VIDEO_STREAM_CONFIG_CAPS vscc;
                VIDEOINFOHEADER* pvih = NULL;

                for (int index=0; index<count; ++index)
                {
                    hr = pISC->GetStreamCaps(index, &pmt, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&vscc));
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        TCHAR       buffer[128];
                        float       frameRate;
                        char*       pixelFormatString;

                        ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

                        pvih = (VIDEOINFOHEADER*)pmt->pbFormat;
                        //
                        if (pvih->bmiHeader.biBitCount == 16)
                            pixelFormatString = TEXT("8 bit 4:2:2 YUV");
                        else if (pvih->bmiHeader.biBitCount == 20)
                            pixelFormatString = TEXT("10 bit 4:2:2 YUV");
                        else if (pvih->bmiHeader.biBitCount == 30)
                            pixelFormatString = TEXT("10 bit 4:4:4 RGB");
                        else
                            pixelFormatString = TEXT("");           


                        if (486 == pvih->bmiHeader.biHeight)
                        {
                            if (417083 == pvih->AvgTimePerFrame)
                            {
                                StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("NTSC - %s (3:2 pulldown removal)"), pixelFormatString);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("NTSC - %s"), pixelFormatString);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (576 == pvih->bmiHeader.biHeight)
                        {
                            StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("PAL - %s"), pixelFormatString);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            frameRate = (float)UNITS / pvih->AvgTimePerFrame;

                            if (720 == pvih->bmiHeader.biHeight)
                            {
                                // 720p
                                if ((frameRate - (int)frameRate) > 0.01)
                                {
                                    StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("HD 720p %.2f - %s"), frameRate, pixelFormatString);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("HD 720p %.0f - %s"), frameRate, pixelFormatString);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (1080 == pvih->bmiHeader.biHeight)
                            {
                                if ((frameRate < 25) || (frameRate >= 50.0))        // 1080p23, 1080p24, 1080p50, 1080p5994, 1080p60
                                {
                                    // Progressive 1080
                                    if ((frameRate - (int)frameRate) > 0.01)
                                    {
                                        StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("HD 1080p %.2f - %s"), frameRate, pixelFormatString);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("HD 1080p %.0f - %s"), frameRate, pixelFormatString);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Interlaced 1080
                                    if ((frameRate - (int)frameRate) > 0.01)
                                    {
                                        StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("HD 1080i %.2f - %s"), frameRate*2.0f, pixelFormatString);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("HD 1080i %.0f - %s"), frameRate*2.0f, pixelFormatString);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if (1556 == pvih->bmiHeader.biHeight)
                            {
                                if ((frameRate - (int)frameRate) > 0.01)
                                {
                                    StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("2K 1556p %.2f - %s"), frameRate, pixelFormatString);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    StringCbPrintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), TEXT("2K 1556p %.0f - %s"), frameRate, pixelFormatString);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // If the display mode was recognized, add it to the listbox UI
                        if (buffer[0] != 0)
                        {
                            // add the item description to combo box
                            int n = m_videoFormatCtrl.AddString(buffer);
                            // store media type pointer in item's data section
                            m_videoFormatCtrl.SetItemData(n, (DWORD_PTR)pmt);

                            // set default format
                            if ((pvih->AvgTimePerFrame == m_vihDefault.AvgTimePerFrame) &&
                                (pvih->bmiHeader.biWidth == m_vihDefault.bmiHeader.biWidth) &&
                                (pvih->bmiHeader.biHeight == m_vihDefault.bmiHeader.biHeight) &&
                                (pvih->bmiHeader.biBitCount == m_vihDefault.bmiHeader.biBitCount))
                            {
                                m_videoFormatCtrl.SetCurSel(n);
                                pISC->SetFormat(pmt);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DeleteMediaType(pmt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_videoFormatCtrl.AddString(TEXT("ERROR: Unable to retrieve video formats"));
            }
        }
    }

    // as the device is being changed, update the IDecklinkInputStatus interface
    {
        CAutoLock lock(&m_csInputStatusLock);   // prevent thread from using this interface while it is changed

        m_pIDecklinkStatus = m_pVideoCapture;
        if (m_pIDecklinkStatus)
        {
            m_pIDecklinkStatus->RegisterVideoStatusChangeEvent((unsigned long)m_hInputStatusChangeEvent);   
        }
    }
}
else
{
    hr = E_POINTER;
}

return hr;
}
```

Now of course i tried changing this:
"if ((frameRate < 25) || (frameRate >= 50.0))"

to
"if ((frameRate < 30) || (frameRate >= 50.0))"

But that just renames the 1080 50i / 59,94i / 60i to 25p / 29.97p / 30p.
I doesn't give me the ability to use 30p, it just is renamed as 30p but captures still 60i.

Maybe someone more experienced can figure out the Problem. I think it has something to do with DirectShow interpresing i.e. 59.94i as a framerate of 29.97 and so it can't populate that framerate twice.

Thanks in advance (and sorry for any misspells -> from Germany),
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blackmagic offers their SDK as a primary API and then their DirectShow filters are built on top of this SDK. That is, DirectShow filters offer a subset of SDK functionality, and this is where in particular you see issues with interlaced/progressive media type overlap (their filters don't do interlaced capture in terms of delivering video feed with truely interlaced media type, or by fields), you are basically limited to what the filter makes available.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I would've use the API, but I found it really hard (especially with limited programming skills) to build a simple software that allows recording to a file and taking screenshots. In this case the DirectShow Capture/record sample was great.

Comment: Is there any example using the "native" API that has a recorder built in.
I want a full screen application (Media Express does not support fullscreen of the preview window) with a recorder and screenshot function.
Screenshot will not be the problem, as I can implement a simple capture of the whole screen

Comment: The problematic part is decent video encoder (typically H.264 encoder, in turn) - they are typically not free, so they are not available out of the box. One typically takes a third party video encoder or uses Windows Media or M-JPEG encoder. Then choice of encoder has implication on container (file) format. I see you are using stock video filter because it's easy to use. I would suggest [WM ASF Writer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318239%28) filter as the easiest to record to file, even though it needs some tricky setup.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to leave the whole DirectShow idea as it seems that the Problem with the framerate will not be an easy fix.
I looked into an example of the native API and there they use OpenGL to paint the Frames into the Preview Window (they re using PaintGL).

The example works perfectly with the two Video framerates. 
The last question not if course is: How do i grab ab Video of the OpenGL stream and record it preferrably to uncompressed AVI.